# How to prove that I will return back to my country of origin?

Tags: schengen, business-travel, proof-of-onward-travel, schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen, currently residing in India. I have been invited for an interview in the Netherlands, fully sponsored by the company. I have all the necessary documents except one, the documents proving that I will
return to my own country after my trip. Unfortunately I am not employed right now and do not have any immovable assets under my name (living with my parents in their house).

How do I prove that I will be returning after the interview? Will a travel itinerary with the return dates be enough? I would be staying there for 3 days.

EDIT: I got the visa. I attached my short professional profile with all the evidence (I have a Master's degree from the US and worked there in a research lab for about 3 years; I think this helped) and also mentioned in the cover letter that I would not be jeopardizing my chance of legally immigrating by illegally overstaying in the Schengen area.

Thanks for the help people!

Comment: If your return travel itinerary is all you have then you should still apply. You may get the visa. If you don't apply then you definitely won't get a visa! Have a plan b, such as interview by Skype

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already cleared the skype round and this job is based in a lab where face to face interview is required.

Comment: A travel itinerary should be acceptable. To make it an even stronger looking application you can buy refundable flight tickets as well, which you can cancel in case you do not get the visa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't really "prove that you *will* return to your country", and generally consulates don't set the bar quite that high (or nobody would ever get a visa). It's sufficient to show that it will be *in your own best interests* to return home after your trip.

When applying for a visa for *tourism* (which is the situation most of the visa advice you'll find on the net will be contemplating), consulates like to see documentation that you're so well rooted in your local community that you wouldn't *want* to go abroad for work.  This is clearly impossible when you're going for a job interview -- the fact that you're going at all is proof positive that you're willing to consider moving away for work. So don't even try to give your situation that spin; it won't be credible.

In the case of a job interview where the host company pays for your trip, that fact will itself be what saves the day. This is evidence that you have a pretty good shot at getting *legal* work and residence in the Netherlands (after all, they wouldn't pay for also-rans to fly halfway around the word). If you overstayed, you would be throwing that prospect away, which is generally reason enough for a consular officer to think you probably won't overstay. Even if you don't get this particular job, just the fact that you have the knowledge and skills to land the interview means that you can probably find something legal elsewhere, which is much preferable to life as an undocumented (and thus probably ill-paid) immigrant in Europe. That's what counts for the visa officer.

Like any visa applicant, you do need to explain your circumstances at home, and document them to the extent those particular circumstances can reasonably be documented. But don't sweat that, and don't try to pretty up reality.

And of course you need to document your itinerary, but you know that.

(This is all assuming that the company that invited you is reputable and law-abiding, and the position you're interviewing for is one where they have a good chance of sponsoring you for a work and residence permit later. But if they aren't, something is fishy anyway, and in that case you don't want to waste your time by going).

Comment: Thank you for a well articulated answer. The company is actually quite big with offices in all the continents and I also have a Master's degree from the US with work experience in the US, in an renowned R&D lab. Your answer gave me some peace. Thanks a lot Henning!

Comment: Should I add my CV or resume with the application? It does not ask for it but concerning my situation I thought I can add my short professional profile. Would that be okay?

Answer (score 0):

If the company sponsoring you is reputed, that should help, as they would not not like to be responsible for you not returning home. I assume the company is sending you tickets, so that can be included in your application along with your bank statement and any previous tax returns.

Comment: The company won't be responsible for returning OP home if he overstays, that's not how it works.

Comment: The company wont have to return the overstaying person home but it can affect how their sponsorship of visa applicants will be looked at in future. I was once invited by a leading Dutch company and they were reluctant to extend the duration of my stay by even a day ,for sightseeing, as they were very conscious of not wanting to sponsor any part of the trip that was not strictly business.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you will be asked for a bank guarantee for a large sum of money or a certified bank statement showing that you have a large sum in deposit at a local bank. That's how it works for visa applicants in Pakistan. The idea is that you have a large sum of money that you will lose if you don't return to your country of origin.

Comment: And if that large sum of money doesn't come from regular income then you get into trouble with your visa because they will assume that something dodgy is going on.

Comment: Oh you misunderstand. People in developing countries who can afford to travel to Europe or get an American degree usually come from money. Also embassies are not tax authorities. In third world countries tax evasion is the norm not the exception. They can demand bank statements all they like but if they try to enforce taxation laws no one will ever travel to their countries and they will lose out on all that brain gain they are after.